# Getting the selected value on a Django forms.ChoiceField

Tags: django, django-forms

i'm working on Django and i need to know how can i get selected value in `forms.ChoiceField`

forms.py

```
class FilterForm(forms.Form):
    continent = forms.ChoiceField(choices=Select_continent())
```

i tried with :
views.py

```
def Select_continent():
    db = MySQLdb.connect("localhost", "root", "aqw", "PFE_Project")
    cursor = db.cursor()
    sql = "SELECT Continent FROM myform_servercomponents"

    try:
        cursor.execute(sql)
        results = cursor.fetchall()
        continents = []
        i=0
        for row in results:
            continents.append(('i',row[0]))
            i+=1
    except:
        print "Error: unable to fetch data"
    db.close()
    return continents
def affiche_all(request, currency):
    if request.method == 'POST':                                                                                                                                                 
        form = FilterForm(request.POST)                                                                                                                                            
        if form.is_valid() : 
            Continent = form.cleaned_data['Continent']
            Continent = dict(form.fields['Continent'])[Continent]
            url = reverse('affiche_all', args=(),   kwargs={'continent': Continent})
            return HttpResponseRedirect(url)
```

but `Continent` always return the last value in `ChoiceField` and what i need is the selected one.
any suggestions?

Comment: What is the continents function or instance you set the choices equal to in forms.py? Might have something to do with what's being done there. `forms.cleaned_data['Continent']` should be all you need to get the selected value.

Answer (score 2):

`dict(form.fields['Continent'])` looks strange, do you mean:

```
continent = dict(continents())[form.cleaned_data['Continent']]
# or
continent = dict(form.fields['Continent'].choices)[form.cleaned_data['Continent']]
```

P.S. I've used `continent` instead of `Continent` as the variable name. The name w/ first uppercase is used for naming class normally.

Comment: always getting the last value in my ChoiceField

Comment: @AmineAntri What's your `ChoiceField.choices` look like? Or How does the `continents()` work?

Comment: i retieve all the continents from my DB

Comment: @AmineAntri `continent = forms.ChoiceField(choices=Select_continent())` accesses DB as soon as `forms.py` is imported, this might cause problem. You'd better to use `ModelChoiceField` and a `QuerySet`. Try to hardcode some continents in code and return them from `continents()` to see whether result changes.

Comment: i don't get what you mean do you have some documentations about what you just said !!